# Escaping data before import into database

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a function in a WordPress plugin that takes a csv file and reads the data into a MySQL database table. Works fine except the raw data is not properly escaped and apostrophes cause issues. My code is below. How can I fix this issue?

```
if (($handle = fopen($file_url, "r")) !== FALSE) {
$j = -1;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
foreach($data as $i => $content) {
    $data[$i] = $data[$i];
}
$wpdb->query( "INSERT INTO games ( id, game_id, date, time, field, hteamno, vteamno, hcoach, vcoach, division, friendly, pool ) VALUES('" . implode("','", $data) . "') ");

$j++;
```

}

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`$wpdb->prepare()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) with placeholders of the appropriate types (eg `%s` for string) to prepare your SQL string.

Or you could use [`$wpdb->insert()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Examples_6), which also allows placeholders, leaving WordPress to do the work.